# Explain the working of sizeof() operator in the following program?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
float a=10.5;
printf("%d%d",sizeof(a),sizeof(10.5));
}
```

OUTPUT:
4 8

I want to know why it happens?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In C a floating point literal is actually a double unless you suffix it with an f (i.e. `10.5f`).

Answer (score 3):

In a nutshell, the reason you get `8` in the second case is that floating point literals are treated by the compiler as `double`.

Using a floating-point literal would fix the discrepancy:

```
printf("%d%d",sizeof(a),sizeof(10.5F));
```

This prints

```
4 4
```

[Demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/iIK2yg).

Answer (score 3):

Here   `sizeof(a)` is size of a float while `sizeof(10.5)` is a size of double.

Answer (score 0):

Floating-point literals (like `10.5`) have type `double`, which is usually 8 bytes wide.

`a` instead is a `float` because you explicitly declared it as such (notice that in its initialization there's an implicit cast from `double` to `float`).

If you want to specify a `float` literal, append `f` to it (`sizeof(10.5f)` is normally 4).

Answer (score 0):

sizeof() returns the size of any datatype, measured in number of bytes required to represent the type. (From Wikipedia)

In this case a is float, and float type requiere 4 bytes.
The second number, 10.5, is double type, and it require 8 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Because here

```
a is of type float (4-Byte)
and when you just use literal decimal like 10.5 it's 
treated as double (8-Byte).
```

Hope that explains your question.

Answer (score 0):

This is because standard says about `sizrof` operator that:

#### C11: 6.5.3.4:

> The `sizeof` operator yields the size (in bytes) of its operand, which may be an
>   expression or the parenthesized name of a type. **The size is determined from the type of
>   the operand**. The result is an integer. If the type of the operand is a variable length array
>   type, the operand is evaluated; otherwise, the operand is not evaluated and the result is an
>   integer constant.

So, whatever be the value of operand of `sizeof` operator it determines the size from the type (data type: `char, int, double, long ....`) of the operand.

Answer (score 0):

Floating point literals like `10.5` are of type `double`. When you do `float a = 10.5`, the double is implicitly being converted to a float.

`10.5f` is a `float` literal, so `sizeof(10.5f)` should return the same thing as `sizeof(float)`.